# Router on Xen's dom0

Tags: virtualization, router, xen

*Is it possible to run a full router on Xen's dom0 between a real (physical) LAN and the Internet, with ocasional domU's booting up as I need them?*

*What problems should I be aware of?*

*Any particular tips?*

*Is there any big performance hit, if the processor doesn't support hardware virtualization?* (just for the dom0, not for domU's, which won't stay up for long anyway).

I want to have it "just in case". I know I will need the virtual instances, and when I need them, I want to create them as hassle-free as possible, without having to reboot the router every time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to have a hypervisor be just a hypervisor, but I don't see any problems turning it in the router.

But I would recommend to set up a virtual router in the DomU, with a paravirtualization you shouldn't face any serious performance problems. Especially when you switch some time to vt-x + vt-d and will be able to passthru a physical network card inside a guest.

We have such virtual routers in the production, running RouterOS on a single Xeon core (even without a direct access to the card) and routing 700-800mbit IPSec without any problems.

Comment: Could you please give more details on the hardware specs of that server? It would be great to have some hands-on data I could relate to. Thanks.

Comment: usual machines, nothing special. i.e. one router is installed on the single core of E5335 (actually now it's running on a 2 cores), another one on a core of E5420 etc. Supermicro server boards with Intel network cards. Currently we use VMWare ESXi, RouterOS doesn't support Xen (but it runs very well on ESXi & KVM). But I'm sure with Xen it could perform even better (in a comparsion with ESXi/KVM without vt-d). For Xen you may choose Vyatta or make a router from any Linux distro you like.

Comment: actually a couple of months ago we've replaced all physical routers with a virtual ones, except the places where we need more than 1-2 gigabits. They do all everyday tasks: routing, filtering, nat, IPsec, OSPF without any problems. and I guess it's much more reliable then having a physical appliance. The physical routers die very rarely but the virtual will never die :)

The modern x86 cores are fast and cheap and in many tasks can perform equal or even beat some network-optimized processor units.